# how to simulate keypess event when click some element in js or vue not jquery

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keyboard

The information you should know to understand what i want to do:

- There was used [ui-element](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) (multi select ) in vue.
- This website's features will use on monoblock with touchscreen (no
  keyboards ). And user's using windows virtual keyboard to fill up the some forms
- There are some reasons i don't want use windows virtual keyboard. And want to create custom keyboard( already created and styled with css) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVhNH.png)

**What i came across with:**

- when i try to set value of input [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoSIV.jpg)
- when i type some character from my keyboard [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6RMT.jpg). (this is what i really want to do with my custom keyboard)

**My Question**

- How can i simulate keypress event when i click some character from my custom keyboard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47454979/392102

Comment: @RoyJ instead of element i use my focused input. is that right? i did it bu not work

Comment: Yes, that should work.